# Munit cannot create inner bean

Tags: spring, mule, munit

caused by: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to lookup beans of type interface org.mule.api.construct.FlowConstruct from the Spring registry
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.internalLookupByTypeWithoutAncestors(SpringRegistry.java:354) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.lookupEntriesForLifecycle(SpringRegistry.java:368) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.lookupObjectsForLifecycle(SpringRegistry.java:241) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.lookupObjectsForLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:155) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:77) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'member-process-api-main': Cannot resolve reference to bean '_muleContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '_muleContext' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:786) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:411) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely I've had a very similar error today...I worked around it by adding a PropertyPlaceholder and attaching an empty property file to it.

[image]